# Jump from breakpoint to breakpoint in ModelSim

Tags: vhdl, verilog, simulation, modelsim

Is there a way to jump from breakpoint to breakpoint while debugging any design (VHDL or Verilog entry) in ModelSim ?

Comment: [modelsim/getting_started](http://www.tkt.cs.tut.fi/tools/public/tutorials/mentor/modelsim/getting_started/gsms.html#debugging) Section 3.4.3.

Comment: Wouldn't the "Run" button work this way?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, _run_ will make the simulation run through to the end of specified time without considering the breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run -all` moves the control to the next breakpoint.

Comment: It would be good if you could expand this to include how to set the break points as well, then the Question and answer will stand on its own. thanks.